# How to remove wordpress directory slash

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect, htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have installed a website in my domain directory like `example.com/website`.

The main issue or problem is that it redirects me to `example.com/website/`.

I never want redirection and I just want that my subdirectory website never redirects me.

I want to do it so that the user can access my website without the last slash it means `example.com/website`.

Can I do this using a PHP function or also kindly share `.htaccess` code if it is possible.

I have read many articles or even question asked by users on stack exchange related trailing slash but no benefit.

Also I have tried out various `.htaccess` codes but no benefit.

Kindly help me with this.

Comment: Have you tried: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R]

Comment: I have checked it what this not work. kindly share the full htaccess code.

Comment: @phillsav_ That directive targets non-directories, so it will never match the _directory_ in which WordPress is installed. However, if you simply try to remove the trailing slash on directories without first disabling the `DirectorySlash` then it will trigger a redirect loop as it will conflict with mod_dir. (You need to prevent the trailing slash being appended in the first place.)

Answer (score 0):

> The main issue or problem is that it redirects me to `example.com/website/`

By default Apache (mod_dir) will "fix" the URL with a 301 redirect to append the trailing slash if it is omitted from a filesystem directory. This is necessary for other Apache features to function correctly...

- without the trailing slash, the `DirectoryIndex` document is not served and a 403 Forbidden response will result (unless `Options Indexes` is enabled in which case you'll get a directory listing despite the presence of an index document - a potential security vulnerability, see below).
- If the request is `/website` (no trailing slash) then mod_rewrite directives in the `/website/.htaccess` file will not trigger (so the WordPress front-controller will fail).

It is possible to prevent Apache (mod_dir) from appending the trailing slash on the `/website` directory (using `DirectorySlash Off`), however, we must then take additional steps to workaround the above issues and manually append the trailing slash (or rewrite directly to the WP front-controller) with an internal rewrite. We also can't do this from within the `/website/.htaccess` file - this must be moved to the document root (the parent directory).

For example:

1. Move the existing WordPress `/website/.htaccess` file to the parent directory (document root), ie. `/.htaccess`.
2. You will then need to make changes like the following to the `/.htaccess` file and the WordPress front-controller:

```
# mod_autoindex must be disabled
# Otherwise your site will be vulnerable to "information disclosure"
Options -Indexes

# Prevent mod_dir appending the trailing slash to filesystem directories
DirectorySlash Off

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /website

# Remove trailing slash from "/website/" if requested directly
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(website)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Route requests for the directory itself (ie. the "homepage")
# (The DirectoryIndex is not otherwise triggered.)
RewriteRule ^website/?$ index.php [L]

# Front controller for all other URLs of the form "/website/<something>"
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^website/. index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

Since we've had to customise the `# BEGIN WordPress` section, you must prevent WordPress from overwriting this and creating another (default) `.htaccess` file in the `/website/` subdirectory.

The above will also canonicalise any requests for `/website/` (with a trailing slash) and redirect to `/website` in order to remove the trailing slash. You should test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect in order to avoid potential caching issues.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing since the earlier 301 redirect (by mod_dir/Apache) to append the trailing slash will have been cached by the browser.

Note that the `DirectorySlash Off` directive applies to all subdirectories. So, if any other subdirectories should be accessible (unlikely I would think) then you will need to take additional steps.

> Can i do this using a php function

The appending of the trailing slash has nothing to do with PHP - it is an Apache "feature". However, you do need to ensure that WordPress is still able to route the URL, since the requested URL-path is now `/website`, and not `/website/` (which is technically a different URL).

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash
  Note the security warning on that page that I've mentioned above:

> **Security Warning**
> Turning off the trailing slash redirect may result in
> an information disclosure. Consider a situation where mod_autoindex is
> active (Options +Indexes) and DirectoryIndex is set to a valid
> resource (say, index.html) and there's no other special handler
> defined for that URL. In this case a request with a trailing slash
> would show the index.html file. But a request without trailing slash
> would list the directory contents.

Comment: It shows me ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: What URL are you requesting? What is the nature of the redirect loop? What is it redirecting from/to? Have you cleared your browser cache? Please add the contents of your `.htaccess` file (now located in the document root) to your question.